# Installing .NET application with database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, deployment, setup-deployment, installshield-le

finally, with the help of Stackoverflow, i managed to finished my project.

the last problem that i encountered is during installation.

i created my installer using installshield limited edition.

the installer includes .net 2.0 sp2, .net 4.0, windows installer 4.5, and sql server 2008 express.

inside the files, i included the database file, which is .MDF (i.e. ThesisDB.mdf)

by default, it will be installed in C:\Program Files

after installation, the current location of the database is:

C:\ProgramFiles\HealthAndFitnessAppTest\My Product Name\

here is the trick that i did with my connection string, my connection string is,

Dim CN As New SqlConnection
("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\ProgramFiles\HealthAndFitnessAppTest\My Product Name\ThesisDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

but an error appears...

"an attempt to attach an auto-named database failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

unfortunately, the trick didnt worked. sorry guys, can you please give me an idea on how will i properly deploy my application together with its database?

Comment: I'd recommend using a relative path in your connection string. What happens if the user decides to install you app in a different path, instead of the one typed?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a space missing between Program and Files in the path?

Comment: AttachDbFilename=C:\ProgramFiles should be AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files.  Though I wouldn't think this causes the error

Comment: i think it is not the problem, i once attached that database to a sql server on my laptop. maybe that is causing the problem, on the error. it shows the previous location of the database. which is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ThesisDB.mdf...

this is the complete error:

"an attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ThesisDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Comment: this is my prev connection string:
Dim CN As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ThesisDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

Comment: guys, i tried this one, i pasted the database file, which is ThesisDB.mdf in this location 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA
and it worked. my theory is that , my application still recognizes the connection string in my laptop. i think the mdf file has its own connection string?